# Can't get value of Textarea form using ckeditor at first submit but it works for second submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I use `CKEditor` textarea which is involved to form area.
I need to get form data on submit using `serializeArray()` jQuery function.
At first submit, it returns value ''.
and after second submit, it returns correct value.
I noticed that textarea value doesn't update first time but for second time.

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // not sure if you wanted this, but I thought I'd add it.
        // get an associative array of just the values.
        var values = $(this).serializeArray();

        var datas = {};
        values.forEach(element => {
            datas[element['name']] = element['value'].replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ckeditor is jQuery library so you should get its value by using below code

```
var desc = CKEDITOR.instances['DSC'].getData();
```

Or if you instance is already define then you can get value as below.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
alert(editor.getData());
```

Check working example at https://codepen.io/rohitmittal/pen/jdYXGe

You should get all form field value in form serialize instead of ckeditor. If it is getting value on second time, I assume it will show last updated value. If you update the value second time, it will still show you the last value not recently updated. So I prefer to use above mentioned syntax to get ckeditor value and add that in form serialized array.

Comment: Hi, Rohit.
CKEDITOR.instances['DSC'].getData();
Here 'DSC' means name of textarea element. right?
I tried but it also returns null at first time.

Comment: yes, DSC means name of textarea, Try it with CKEDITOR.instances.DSC.getData(); if it works. If it doesn't work, can you please create a fiddle or pen so I can check there?

Comment: It's not working.
well, this is complicated thing.
All contents are generated dynamically.

Comment: <textarea name="element_563" id="" class="form-control ckeditor-default  processed-ckeditor-default" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>

Comment: This is original textarea and ckeditor created after.

CKEDITOR.instances['element_563'].getData()
CKEDITOR.instances.element_563.getData()

I tried with these but both returns null.

Comment: I have updated answer with a working example for you. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_jquery.html and https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_Adapters_jQuery.html#method-val.

CKEditor has jQuery Adapter which allows you using both, editor internal API as well as jQuery methods. To get HTML from editor, please use:

```
$( '#editor1' ).val( )
```